# Iterate enum abstracts in Haxe

Tags: enums, enumeration, haxe

How can enum abstracts be iterated to obtain a list of key value pairs?

Example:

```
@:enum
abstract ExampleEnumAbstract(UInt) {
    public var value1 = 0x0;
    public var value2 = 0x1;
    public var value3 = 0x2;
}
```

For enum instances, this could be accomplished such as:

```
enum ExampleEnum {
    Value1;
    Value2;
    Value3;
}

for(value in Type.allEnums(ExampleEnum))
    trace(value);
}
```

Not sure if this is the best approach - I can obtain keys; however, am unable to obtain values, as in:

```
var keys:Array<String> = Type.getClassFields(ExampleEnumAbstract)

for (key in keys) {
    trace(key + " = " + ExampleEnumAbstract[key]);
}
```

Trying to obtain value that way gives compile time error:

> String should be Int
>   Array access is not allowed on `Class<ExampleEnumAbstract.ExampleEnumAbstract_Impl_>`

Ultimately a `map` of key value pairs would be ideal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I know there is no specification on that. Enum abstracts are a bit hackish and are generally used just for bindings and low level optimization. I doubt it will be possible to expect rtti working properly with them in near future and on all platforms (same goes for all the abstracts, by the way).

So, the best actual approach would be to just

```
@:enum abstract ExampleEnumAbstract(UInt) {
    public var value1 = 0x0;
    public var value2 = 0x1;
    public var value3 = 0x2;
    public static function getConstructorsValues():Map<String, UInt> return [
      'value1' => 0,
      'value2' => 1,
      'value3' => 2,
    ];
}
```

You can also make a macro generating this (or similar) function for you.

Going back to your `ExampleEnumAbstract[key]` code: of course it won't work. You *can* make it to work by using `Reflect.field`, however it is not guaranteed the values even *exist* in runtime.